# get twitter home timeline tweets using spark streaming and scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter, spark-streaming, twitter4j

How could I get twitter home timeline tweets using spark streaming and scala?

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
val output = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
```

When I use createStream, it doesn't return my timeline.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get home timeline tweets using Spark Streaming and Scala, we need to set Twitter OAuth credentials using `TwitterFactory` in `twitter4j`.

```
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken

// Twitter Authentication credentials
  val consumerKey = "twitter_consumer_key"
  val consumerSecret = "twitter_consumer_secret"
  val accessToken = "twitter_access_token"
  val accessTokenSecret = "twitter_access_token_secret"

  // Authorizing with your Twitter Application credentials
  val twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance()
  twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
  twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(accessToken, accessTokenSecret))

  // Setting up streaming context with a window of 10 seconds
  val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
  val output = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, Option(twitter.getAuthorization()))
```

Or if you do not want to set the access credentials in `ssc` then you can use following code:

```
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", "twitter_consumer_key")
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", "twitter_consumer_secret")
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", "twitter_access_token")
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", "twitter_access_token_secret")


val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
val output = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None)
```

For a full fledged example on Spark Streaming and Scala, refer following example: [knolx-spark-streaming](https://github.com/knoldus/knolx-spark-streaming)

Comment: I did same and I set the access credentials in ssc, but it receives a global stream of tweets and not from the timeline.